# Logic Gate's Scheme

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I have a logic gate function like this :

(A+B)•A+(A’•C)

but i dont understand how to make the logic gate scheme based on that function, can anyone help me ?

I'm sorry if my English is bad.
thank's before

Comment: First you need to simplify you're function... then build it

Comment: When you simplify the boolean expression, it will be very simple. If I have done it correctly, only 1 logic gate is needed (it's been a few years since doing this!)

Comment: @MCG - it may simplify more than that :)

Comment: @PeterSmith simplify to less than a single logic gate? How is that possible? Lol

Comment: @MCG - my mistake; I didn't see the inversion in the (A`C) :)

Comment: @PeterSmith admittedly I missed it at first! Wonder if OP will make an appearance again..... Or maybe they aren't botherted about actually getting help!

Answer (score -1):

first you need to simplify the function so"
A(A+B)=A + AB = A
So simplified circuit is :
A+ A'C

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, arsalan. We give homework questions special treatment by prompting the OP (original poster) with some hints, ask them to update their question and then give more guidance until they've, mostly, figured it out by themselves. Providing a full solution as you have done isn't very helpful to the OP and not very helpful to the site. You have the option of hiding your answer for a while by deleting it (and undeleting it later) or by prompting the OP on how to do the first step of the solution. Hit the [edit] link below your question.

Comment: thanks for your mention, I'll keep it in mind